# BackgroundWorker RunWorkerCompleted twice when work complete

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin, backgroundworker

I am writing a `listview` which can dynamically load more data when user has scroll down to the end. When user scroll at the end, the `listview` will move up and a `progressbar` show up. When the data fetching is ready, the `listview` will move down and the `progressbar` disappear.

So I use background worker to implement this. But I found when load data for the second time, the `RunWorkerCompleted` method always run twice, which can cause error. But I can't figure it out.

This is my onScrollStateChanged:

```
mListView.ScrollStateChanged += delegate(object sender, AbsListView.ScrollStateChangedEventArgs e) {
    int threshold=1;
    int listviewCount=mListView.Count;

    if(e.ScrollState==ScrollState.Idle){
        if(mListView.LastVisiblePosition>=(listviewCount-threshold))
        {
            if(!isLoadingMore)
            {
                count++;
                Log.Info("load Times",count.ToString());

                //toggle loading state bool to true
                isLoadingMore=!isLoadingMore;

                //start progressbar
                ListViewUPAndprogressbarStart();
                Log.Info("mContainer","Going up");

                mWorker.DoWork+=delegate(object sender1, DoWorkEventArgs e1) {
                    BackgroundWorker mworker = sender1 as BackgroundWorker;

                    if (mworker.CancellationPending == true) {
                        e1.Cancel = true;
                    } else {
                        //do work example
                        Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    }
                };

                mWorker.RunWorkerCompleted+=delegate(object sender1, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e1) {
                    //end progressbar
                    ListViewDOWNAndprogressbarEnd();
                    Log.Info("mContainer","Going down");
                    if (e1.Cancelled == true) {

                    } else if (!(e1.Error == null)) {

                    } else {
                        //work complete add more data
                        for (int i=beginList; i < beginList+addList; i++) {
                            mExpandableListItemAdapter.Add (string.Format("Object "+i.ToString()));
                            mExpandableListItemAdapter.danWeiXinXi.Add (string.Format("This is object"+i.ToString()+"'s information"));
                        }
                        beginList=beginList+addList;
                    }

                    //toggle loading state bool to false when complete
                    isLoadingMore=!isLoadingMore;
                };

                if (mWorker.IsBusy != true) {
                    mWorker.RunWorkerAsync ();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Info("load fail","loading data and can't start backgroundworker");
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And this is my debug output:

```
[load Times] 1
[mContainer] Going up
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #2
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #3
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
[Mono] DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/libc.so'.
[Mono] DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/libc.so'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/libc.so'      ('/system/lib/libc.so').
[Mono] Searching for 'gettid'.
[Mono] Probing 'gettid'.
[Mono] Found as 'gettid'.
[mContainer] Going down
[load Times] 2
[mContainer] Going up
[load fail] loading data and can't start backgroundworker
[mContainer] Going down
[mContainer] Going down
[load fail] loading data and can't start backgroundworker
[load fail] loading data and can't start backgroundworker
[load fail] loading data and can't start backgroundworker
```

the mContainer tag's going down and going up should in pairs so that this function correctly. But the second time there are two "going down". Can anyone help me fix this? Thanks :)

Comment: Are you ever cleaning up your registered delegate handlers?

Comment: "mWorker.DoWork+=delegate" You add another handler on each pass... so you are going to end up with 3 calls the next time, then 4, etc...

Comment: @mariocatch Do you mean using `mBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted -= mBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;` ? Where should I put this unregisteration? Inside the `RunWorkerCompleted` or some where else? I can fix my problem by putting `mWorker = new BackgroundWorker ();` inside my `ScrollStateChanged`, but that seems is a ugly solution.

Comment: If you plan on re-using the same worker instance, you'll probably want to not use an anonymous handler for the work and completed delegates. Will need to cache off a variable, and unregister it when it's completed. Or just create a new instance each time.